# OpenLayers performance issues adding features to vector layers

Tags: openlayers, wfs, performance

I have a fairly standard looking setup (standard in my eyes) but my performance is dreadful. My issue is that any fix stands me up for a fairly large reactor so I was hoping to get some advice.

I have a WMTS basemap, a request is made to my WFS to understand all the layers it may provide. User draws a polygon and it builds a request to my WFS server to retrieve data with a filter of this polygon, this request is fired for each of the potential 20 to 30 layers/feature types held in my WFS.
For each data type I create a new OpenLayers VectorLayer, add styling directly to the features on a per layer basis,  and add layer to the map.

The requests to the WFS all come back quickly but drawing each layer on to the map is really really poor. Depending on the data type the user can be waiting up to 20 seconds per layer. Points are quick, Multi Polygons take a long time to render.

I am dealing with a large number of features and I simply can't restrict what is visible so not expecting it to be lightning but the performance is not sufficient.

I am using OpenLayers 5, 6 was just released and when I have understood the changes I will update but looking at the release notes I am not sure it will increase performance.

Has anyone had any similar issues or success stories?

Comment: why are you downloading the features? anytime you try to draw a large number of features then performance will be poor

Comment: @Ian this is not actually the root of the issue. I need to download the features as they need to be displayed on the base map, and each feature is then selectable to view additional data the wfs returns. The large number of features returns within about 2 seconds which is sufficient for the nature of this application. It is then the rendering on the map that takes the ridiculous amount of time. The quick fix is a loading bar so the user knows what that the load or render is incomplete but I feel there is something amiss with my approach here.

Comment: do you have to reproject in OL the features that you get from your WFS ? if so it might be quite heavy indeed so you could try to reproject them in 3857 server-side first.

Comment: Leo this could be it. At the moment I first project to (I cant remember) a proj that turf can understand for the clipping client side, and then I project to 27700 for display. Great idea thank you. I will report back.

Comment: Rendering problems can also be related to how the features are styled.

Comment: Mike, not this, very simplistic styling and the same issues occur when I switch off all styling. Thank you though.